# Why explicit-ness of std::pair's heterogeneous "move"-constructor changed in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, language-lawyer

Pardon the convoluted title, and consider this code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

using X = std::unique_ptr<int>;

using A = std::pair<int, const X>;
using B = std::pair<int,       X>;

static_assert(std::is_constructible<A, B>::value, "(1)"); // Ok.
static_assert(std::is_convertible<B, A>::value, "(2)"); // Rejected by GCC and Clang, in C++14 and before.

static_assert(std::is_constructible<const X, X>::value, "(3)"); // Ok.
static_assert(std::is_convertible<X, const X>::value, "(4)"); // Ok.
```

In short, the constructor of `std::pair<int, const std::unique_ptr<int>>` from an rvalue of type `std::pair<int, std::unique_ptr<int>>` is `explicit` in C++14, and implicit and C++17 and newer. Where does this difference come from?

Only libstdc++ and libc++ demonstrate this behavior. In MSVC's library, the constructor is always implicit.

Why was it `explicit` in C++14? I don't see anything relevant on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) (constructor (6)).

Comment: I suspect deduction guides.  Will need to look at it for awhile.

Comment: It changed because valid points were made regarding some constructors (of pair and tuple) being over constrained. https://wg21.link/n4387 ( Note how the papers moved some pre-conditions into more sfiane friendly constraints as well ).

Comment: BTW, since the paper is from 2015 and it was *it* that made the pair constructors explicit at all (conditionally or otherwise), I'd say MSVC is being the conforming one. Perhaps libstdc++ and libc++ don't preserve true C++14 behaviour here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant constructors have not been `explicit` before C++17 either.

GCC and Clang in pre-C++17 mode are actually considering `std::is_convertible<B, A>::value` false because `A`'s move constructor is implicitly deleted.

The move constructor is implicitly deleted, because a `const std::unique_ptr` cannot be moved or copied.

The move constructor is required to fulfill `std::is_convertible<B, A>::value` before C++17, because it tests whether a function of the form

```
A test() {
    return std::declval<B>();
}
```

would be well-formed. The return statement *copy-initializes* the `A` return value from the operand and before C++17 copy-initialization always involved a conversion to a temporary of the target type if necessary, then followed by direct-initialization of the target from the temporary. That direct-initialization would use the move constructor of `A`. The move can be elided by the compiler, but the move constructor must still be usable.

Since C++17 mandatory copy elision applies and even conceptually the copy-initialization does not contain the direct-initialization via the move constructor anymore.

Comment: This appears to be correct: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hzGW7jK7r